# using iso 15693 NFC tags on Raspberry with rc522

Tags: python, rfid, nfc

Is it possible to read/write ISO 15693 NFC tags using an RC522 chip? So far I do not have much experience with the chip, I downloaded this https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python library but unfortunately nothing happens. With the given ISO-14443 tags it works fine.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MFRC522 supports the ISO/IEC 14443 standard.

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf

I really don't see how it could support a later incompatible standard such as  ISO/IEC 15693.